# How can I deploy my features in a Machine Learning algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, feature-selection

Suppose I have a set of tweets which labeled as negative and positive. I want to perform some sentiment analysis.

I extracted 3 basic features:

1. Emotion icons
2. Exclamation marks
3. Intensity words(very, really etc.).

**How should I use these features with SVM or other ML algorithms?**

In other words, how should I deploy the extracted features in SVM algorithm?
I'm working with python and already know how should I run SVM or other algorithms, but I don't have any idea about the relation between extracted features and role of them in each algorithm!

**Based on the responses of some experts I update my question:**

At first, I wanna appreciate your time and worthy explanations. I think my problem is solving… So in line with what you said, each ML algorithm may need some vectorized features and I should find a way to represent my features as vectors. I want to explain what I got from your explanation via a rudimentary example.

Say I have emoticon icons (for example 3 icons) as one feature:

1-Hence, I should represent this feature by a vector with 3 values.

2-The vectorized feature can initial in this way : [0,0,0] (each value represents an icon = :) and :( and :P ).

3-Next I should go through each tweet and check whether the tweet has an icon or not. For example [2,1,0] shows that the tweet has: :) 2 times, and :( 1 time, and :p no time.

4-After I check all the tweets I will have a big vector with the size of n*3 (n is the total number of my tweets).

5-Stages 1-4 should be done for other features.

6-Then I should merge all those features by using m models of SVM (m is the number of my features) and then classify by majority vote or some other method.
Or should create a long vector by concatenating all of the vectors, and feed it to the SVM.

Could you correct me if there is any misunderstanding?

Comment: should I train my dataset each time with one feature? I read several articles and they are just saying: we should extract features and deploy them in our algorithms but HOW?

Comment: The basic features act as coordinates in a feature-space for your tweets. For supervised learning you need to label your tweets that you consider as training data, as positive or negative and then use SVM or other methods

Comment: Thanks a bunch. But my problem is that I can't understand when and how should I use these features?!!

Comment: for example, in sentiment analysis tasks we all know that an emoticon dictionary is a basic feature and acts as a clue for the sentiment of the tweets. but I have no idea how should I apply this clue to my algorithm

Comment: I would enumerate the emotion icons and use them as integers along with the number of exclamation marks and number of intensity words so that each tweet will have a 3x1 feature vector '(10, 0, 0)' for example along with its label (0 - positive, 1- negative)

Comment: @ZachiShtain In line with what you said I updated my question. Would you please take a look at it to see whether I got the point or not?

Answer (score 4):

basically, to make things **very** "simple" and "shallow", all algorithm takes some sort of a numeric vector represent the features

the real work is to find how to represent the features as vector which yield the best result, this depends by the feature itself and on the algorithm using

for example to use SVM which basically find a separator plane, you need to project the features on some vectors set which yield a good enough separation, so for instance you can treat your features like this:

- **Emotion icons** - create a vector which represent all the icons present in that tweet, define each icon to an index from `1` to `n` so tweet represented by `[0,0,0,2,1]` means the 4th and 5th icons are appearing in his body 2 and 1 times respectively
- **Exclamation marks** - you can simply count the number of occurrences (a better approach will be to represent some more information about it like the place in a sentence and such...)
- **Intensity words** - you can use the same approach as the **Emotion icons**

basically each feature can be used alone in the SVM model to classify good and bad

you can merge all those features by using 3 models of **SVM** and then classify by majority vote or some other method

or

you can create a long vector by concatenating all of the vectors, and feed it to the **SVM**

> this is just a one approach, you might tweak it or use some other one to fit your data, model and goal better

Comment: You would also want to normalize these features between 0 and 1

Comment: At first, I wanna appreciate your time and worthy explanations. I think my problem is solving… So in line with what you said, each ML algorithm may need some vectorized features and I should find a way to represent my features as vectors. I want to explain what I got from your explanation via a rudimentary example:

Comment: Say I have emoticon icons (for example 3 icons) as one feature.
1-Hence, I should represent this feature by a vector with 3 values. 
2-The vectorized feature can initial in this way : [0,0,0] (each value represents an icon = :) and :( and :P ). 
3-Next I should go through each tweet and check whether the tweet has an icon or not. For example [2,1,0] shows that the tweet has: :) 2 times, and :( 1 time, and :p no time.
4-After I check all the tweets I will have a big vector with the size of n*3 (n is the total number of my tweets). 
5-Stages 1-4 should be done for other features.

Comment: 6-Then I should merge all those features by using m models of SVM (m is the number of my features) and then classify by majority vote or some other method.
Or should create a long vector by concatenating all of the vectors, and feed it to the SVM.

Could you please correct me if there is any misunderstanding? If it is not correct I will delete it otherwise I should let it stay cause It can be practical for any beginners such as me...
Thanks a bunch…